# Do Firebase Cloud Messaging Data Messages require requestPermission?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to understand whether you need to call `firebase.messaging().requestPermission()` with messages of type `Data` in Firebase Cloud Messaging.

From what I understand, the data messaging doesn't trigger the standard APN or GCM push notification - thus does it require request permission?  It seems like the request permission triggers the standard iOS push notification permission (I haven't tested it on Android yet).

Does that mean that a user will always have a FCM token even if they don't give the app os permissions for push?

Comment: From what I've found on Android, the FCM token is available regardless of the Notification permission set by the user. More importantly, you can still send messages to the device when the user has switched off Notifications - you just can't generate a system tray noti (quietly does nothing if you try).

Comment: I'm also curious about this, specifically for use in a Flutter Web app, where I just want to receive background messages but not trigger notifications. It seems that in order to get a FCM token, one must first request permission?